# How to run multiple GPU-accelerated Training Jobs concurrently on AI-Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm running tensorflow training jobs on AI Platform using the `"scaleTier": "BASIC_GPU"` setting. My understanding is that this setting uses a single Tesla K80 GPU for my job.

Creating a new job while another job is already running seems to cause the newly created job to be put in a queue until the running job is finished. When I check the logs for the new job, I see this message:

`This job is number 1 in the queue and requires 8.000000 CPUs and 1 K80 accelerators. The project is using 8.000000 CPUs out of 450 allowed and 1 K80 accelerators out of 0 TPU_V2_POD, 0 TPU_V3_POD, 1 K80, 1 P100, 1 V100, 4 P4, 4 T4, 8 TPU_V2, 8 TPU_V3 allowed across all regions.The project is using 8.000000 CPUs out of 20 allowed and 1 K80 accelerators out of 0 TPU_V2_POD, 0 TPU_V3_POD, 1 K80, 1 P100, 1 P4, 1 T4, 1 V100, 8 TPU_V2, 8 TPU_V3 allowed in the region us-central1.`

This [AI Platform documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/quotas#gpu-quota) seems to say that my project should be able to use up to 30 K80 GPUs concurrently.

Why is it that I can't even use 2 concurrently?

Do I need to do something to increase my limit to the expected 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For new projects, the default quota will be very low. You can request the more quota increase through [this form.](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScjm2W208wdf0iyQxBIESZ2_UvTS9xVPKleTQg9r_Uc1uPACQ/viewform)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did try submitting the form you linked. Unfortunately, after 10 days I have yet to receive any response. And I'm still unable to run multiple training jobs at the same time because of the quota limits.

Comment: Yesterday my request to increase the quota was approved. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your project admin has placed a quota on the number of GPUs that you can use (notice the error message says that your quota is 20 cpus, 1 K80, 1 P100 in us-central1), so the job is waiting for a K-80 to become available.

Two options:

(1) Go to console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas
Find Compute Engine API and K80s
Do "Edit Quota", or ask your admin to increase it if necessary.
Make sure to edit both all the regions quota and the us-central1 quota.  Otherwise, if the admin has given you 1 GPU per region, run the job in us-west1 etc.

(2) It seems that you have P100 available, so use a custom scale tier and specify P100.

Comment: AI Platform has its own quota, which is different from Compute Engine Quota. For now, customers will need to file quota increase requests through this form. https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScjm2W208wdf0iyQxBIESZ2_UvTS9xVPKleTQg9r_Uc1uPACQ/viewform